# excel rowndown to c# function for decimal values

Tags: c#, excel, decimal, formula

Hellow friends i want to convert excel `ROUNDDOWN(decimal, -2)`

to c# function give me the solution.I want this for financial calculation.

that is
[From excel based]
=ROUNDDOWN(31415.92654, -2)=31400

Rounds 31415.92654 down to 2 decimal places to the left of the decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Math.Floor(number / 100) * 100`

Or

`Math.Floor(number / ((Decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimal_places))) * (Decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimal_places)`

Comment: not correct i want =ROUNDDOWN(31415.92654, -2)
 

Rounds 31415.92654 down to 2 decimal places to the left of the decimal point.
 

31400

Comment: Oh, so you want to move the decimal place over 2, round down, the move it back 2?

Comment: So maybe you want `Math.Floor(number / 100) * 100`

Comment: correct edit it as answer i will mark it as right answer